# How can I modify/edit/change the media video controls?

Tags: media, files

I was wondering how could I modify the controls from a media video.
In my particular case, I want to remove the "Download" button from the controls, see:
[image: Screenshot of a video player with the control options opened]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest workaround I could find was:

- Create a template on your custom theme for the video field such as `file-video.html.twig`.
- Inside the template, create a video tag and place videos inside a `<source />`, then set a new attribute for the video tag called `ControlsList` with a value of `nodownload`, like this:

```
<video {{ attributes.setAttribute('controlsList', 'nodownload') }}>
  {% for file in files %}
    <source {{ file.source_attributes }} />
  {% endfor %}
</video>
```

You could also set the attribute manually: `<video ControlsList='nodownload'/>`